# Extension Lemma for Smooth Functions proof(Lee)

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

On p.45, John M.Lee gives the proof of Lemma 2.26(Extension Lemma for Smooth Functions).On the second paragraph of the proof, the author mentions in a parenthesis:"The extended function is smooth because the two definitions agree on the open subset $W_{p} \backslash supp\psi_{p}$ where they overlap).I am trying to comprehend the flow of the proof, so my question is:which are the two definitions that the author is talking about?
[image]

Comment: How do we know if we happen not to own the book?

Comment: Edited,don't even know if I am allowed to do that..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For each $p$, let's define a function $F_p\colon M\to\mathbb R^k$ by
$$
F_p(x) =
\begin{cases}
\psi_p(x) \tilde {f_p}(x), & x\in W_p;\\
0, & x\in M\smallsetminus \operatorname{supp} \psi_p.
\end{cases}
$$
These two definitions overlap on the open set $W_p\cap (M\smallsetminus \operatorname{supp} \psi_p) = W_p\smallsetminus \operatorname{supp} \psi_p$, where they both give zero. Therefore $F_p$ is a globally defined smooth function by the gluing lemma for smooth maps (Corollary 2.8 in my book).

In a sitution like this, it's common just to continue denoting the extended function by $\psi_p\tilde {f_p}$ instead of introducing a new name for it like $F_p$, and that's what I did in this proof. This helps to damp down the explosive proliferation of notations that can plague this subject.

Comment: Users of this site are really lucky to get answers straight from the horse's mouth : Jack very generously provides great customer service to his readers !

Comment: It is an honor to get the answer directly from the author,couldn't ask for more,thank you.

Comment: @Jac: You're welcome!